# How to create a feature with feature stapplingin SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am new to SharePoint. I have done basic programs on creating a feature. Got stuck with creating a feature with feature stappling. Can anyone provide me code| logic for this Program?
Thanking you.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

1) Open a new sharepoint visual studio 2010 project

2) Make your feature as normal

3) Find the site definition id you want to staple your feature to

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\1033\XML\webtemp*.xml
```

4) Create a new module, call it "Stapling" or something

5) Insert this into the module file, replacing the site definition template name and feature guid:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="FEATUREGUID" TemplateName="YOURSITETEMPLATE#0" />
</Elements>
```

6) A new feature should have been created for "Stapling", but if it has not, create it and the Stapling module to it

7) Set the deployment scope to "Farm"

8) You should have 2 features in your project now

9) Package and deploy